# Friendly URL in IIS

Tags: iis, proxy, url-rewriting

I have a web service with url like:

```
'https://tgis.ml/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ctw:bwc_bandonen_group@EPSG:900913@png/13/6520/3864.png?flipY=true'
```

In IIS, i want to make frienly url like:

```
'https://tgis.ml/geo/tile/13/6520/3864.png'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem with:

Math URL:
`tile/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+).png`

Rewrite URL:
`http://localhost:3002/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/ctw:bwc_bandonen_group@EPSG:900913@png/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}.png?flipY=true`